# It is 'surprising' that so many portrait paintings hang in art museums, since the subject matter seems to

Tags: sentence-meaning

> It is 'surprising' that so many portrait paintings hang in art
>   museums, since the subject matter seems to dictate a status closer to
>   pictures in the family photograph album than to high art.

I did not understand the intended meaning of the sentence. 
Precisely, the explanation of the author's exclamation.

'since the subject matter seems to dictate' : subject matter means the depictions in the paintings? 'dictate' means that the 'subject matter' depicted in the paintings tell or enunciate?

'a status closer to pictures in a family photograph album' : what does 'status' refer to here?

'than to high art' : high art means a masterpiece. What relevance and meaning does this have here? What is the contrast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author expresses '**surprise**' because according to him/her, portraits are more of a personal type of photography/art and hence belong to a private possession such as a family album.

**'since the subject matter seems to dictate'** : subject matter here  according to the author means the portraits...the personal nature of the works.

*'a status closer to pictures in a family photograph album' : what does 'status' refer to here?*

I would say **status** here refers to position or placement.

**'than to high art'** : *high art means a masterpiece. What relevance and meaning does this have here? What is the contrast?*

High art, as per the author, may mean critically acclaimed art works or something worthy of note. Whereas, in contrast,a  family album can even (but not necessarily) comprise amateurish works. The contrast, the author is trying to draw, is between the widely or critically acclaimed art and the more personal/private album which may or may not comprise works of note.

Comment: Ok, so the intended meaning can be delineated as: the 'subject matter' of portrait paintings is better suited (or compared with) a family album in contrast to being hung at 'art meuseums' that is congruous to 'high art'. Correct?

Comment: better suited "to"..the to was missing. Yes, roughly that can be the delineation.

Comment: and "dictate" (in the sense of mandate, not tell) was a bit strong; the author might better have used "indicate" or "suggest"